# Measuring Side Lengths in 3D Space of a Shape

Tags: 3d

When measuring the side length in 3D space, For the lengthside measurement, between point a (x,y,z) and b (x1,x2,x3) how do you calculate the side length. Is it a -b or b - a?

Comment: doesn't matter as it will be squared

Comment: To put it a different way, would you get a different answer if you measured the distance starting from $a$ and going to $b$ and also measured starting at $b$ and going to $a$?